# ScreenSharing as VNC client/viewer doesn't work in Yosemite

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I was using built in `ScreenSharing` app to connect to a VNC server running on a Linux box.

After upgrading to `Yosemite` the `ScreenSharing` icon on my Dock is a question mark now. Does OS X no longer have a built in VNC client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the application moved (no clue from where to where). All I had to do was enter the path

```
vnc:\\machine.domain.com:5981
```

in a `Safari` tab, and it came to life. Then just drag the icon that shows up near the bottom of the dock to somewhere up in the middle, and it will stay on my Dock just like the old one had (removed the old one).

(Adjust your machine name and port number accordingly, 5900 is the default)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I'd also add that a "Screen Sharing" app will appear in the Dock after you do this Safari method once. You can then select "Keep in Dock" to keep it handy, so you won't have to do this Safari method each time.

Comment: I tried this to connect to a guest VM running under an Ubuntu KVM hypervisor.   Chicken-of-the-VNC can access it just fine but the Screen Sharing app just hangs on connect.

Answer (score 8):

On OS X Yosemite the **Screen Sharing** app moved to the applications subfolder:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications
```